# Topology - A definition of the closure of a set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In the book 'Introduction to Topological Manifolds' (Lee, 2011), the closure of a set is defined as follows:

$A$ is a subset of topological space $X$.
The closure of $A$ in $X$ denoted by $\bar{A}$ is
$$
\bar{A}
=
\cap \left\{B \subset X ~ | ~ A \subset B, ~ B \text{ is closed in }X \right\}
$$

Using the definition, I want to show the following: $X$ is endowed with the metric $d$. Let $c \in X$ and suppose there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(c) \cap A = \emptyset $. Then, $c \notin \bar{A}$.

Such a definition is not familiar to me to handle. I think the proposition is true. I tried supposing $c \in \bar{A}$ and proving it by contradiction. But I couldn't figure out how to express it formally.

Comment: Hint: the complement of $B_\epsilon(c)$ is a closed set that contains $A$ and not $c$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut That was really easy... Thank you